# Provision Profiles are getting invalid after generting certificates using certificate wizard

Tags: codenameone

Once the certificate got generated successfully, the previous active provision profile got invalid.

We are using codename one Certificate wizard to generate certificates.

Answer (score 1):

A provisioning profile includes a reference to the certificate, when you generate a new certificate you revoke the old one. That's why we ask you if you want to replace the old certificate to which you said `Yes`.

The correct approach moving forward is to say `No` and copy the certificate from the previous project. That way the wizard will only generate provisioning.

Comment: Can I copy account  Development and distribution .p12 files, which were created on my first use of generating button and create new provision files in developer account, download and given this paths... is this approach works for me?

Comment: You should keep the same P12 files but should regenerate provisioning for different projects.